# I'm trying to make a smiley face GUI keeps giving me a Null Pointer Exception (NPE) on my JButtons

Tags: java, class, jpanel, jbutton, paintcomponent

I need to set up a standard smiley face GUI where you can wink, blink, smile, and frown with JButtons. I need to do this with three separate classes: a class that draws the smiley face, a class with all my buttons and actionListeners that control the smiley face, and a class with the applet.

I keep getting NPE's on my buttons in the button class. I can't figure out why. Please go easy on me, I'm new to Java.

Here's my controls class:

```
public class SmileyControls extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    Smiley smiley;

    JPanel controlPanel, eyePanel;
    JButton open, wink, shut; // make these an animation???? see loop chapter in text

    public SmileyControls(Smiley smileControl) {

        smiley = smileControl;
        controlLayout();
    }

    public void controlLayout() {

        eyePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        open = new JButton("Open");
        wink = new JButton("Wink");
        shut = new JButton("Shut");

        open.addActionListener(this);
        wink.addActionListener(this);
        shut.addActionListener(this);

        eyePanel.add(open);
        eyePanel.add(wink);
        eyePanel.add(shut);
        add(eyePanel);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource()==open){
            smiley.setEyeCondition(0);  // this calls the method setEyeCondition() from the smiley class that I created. I'm getting my NPE's here
        }
        if(e.getSource()==wink){
            smiley.setEyeCondition(1);  // and here
        }
        if(e.getSource()==shut){
            smiley.setEyeCondition(2);  // and here
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my smiley class:

```
public class Smiley extends JPanel {

    int locX, locY, height, width;
    Color moleColor;
    int eyeCondition;
    Graphics2D g2d;

    public Smiley(int x, int y, int w, int h) {

        locX = x;
        locY = y + 100; // needed to add 100 pixels to make room for hair
        height = h;
        width = w;

        moleColor = new Color(84,60,37);
        eyeCondition = 0;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g2d= (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        setHair();
        setFace();
        setEyes();  // these methods paint the face
        setMole();
        setMouth();
    }

    // CONTROL METHODS

    public void setEyeCondition(int eye) {

        // the int values here are taken from the smileyControls class
        // I think they'd repaint my applet if it weren't for the NPE's

        if(eye == 0) {
            // draw eyes open
            g2d.fillOval(locX+width/5, locY+height/5,width/5, height/5); // left eye
            g2d.fillOval(locX+3*width/5, locY+height/5, width/5, height/5); // right eye
            repaint();
        } else if(eye == 1) {
            // draw wink
            g2d.fillRect(locX+width/5, locY+height/5,width/2, height/20); // left eye winking
            g2d.fillOval(locX+3*width/5, locY+height/5, width/5, height/5); // right eye open
            repaint();
        } else if(eye == 2) {
            // draw blink
            g2d.fillRect(locX+width/5, locY+height/5,width/2, height/20); // left eye blinking
            g2d.fillRect(locX+3*width/5, locY+height/5,width/2, height/20); // right eye blinking
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void setEyes() { // this method paints the original eyes

        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        g2d.fillOval(locX+width/5, locY+height/5,width/5, height/5); // left eye
        g2d.fillOval(locX+3*width/5, locY+height/5, width/5, height/5); // right eye
    }

}
```

And here's my applet:

```
public class SmileyApplet extends JApplet {

    Smiley smiley1;
    SmileyControls control1;

    JPanel container, smileyAndControls1, smileyAndControls2, smileyAndControls3;

    BorderLayout border;

    public void init() {

        border = new BorderLayout();
        setLayout(border);

        setUpContainer();

    }

    public void setUpContainer() {

        container = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        smileyAndControls1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        setUpControl();
        setUpSmiley();

        smiley1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 600));

        smileyAndControls1.add(control1);
        smileyAndControls1.add(smiley1);

        container.add(smileyAndControls1);  // add more controls to master container here

        add(container, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void setUpSmiley() {

        smiley1 = new Smiley(0, 0, 400, 400);
        add(smiley1);
    }

    public void setUpControl() {

        control1 = new SmileyControls(smiley1);
    }

}
```

Comment: where exactly is the `Exception` thrown?

Comment: In the actionPerformed method of the controls class. You'll have to scroll down, the lines are commented

Comment: Don't maintain a reference to a `Graphics` context you didn't create, instead, pass the reference which you are given to the methods which need to use it

Answer (score 0):

At first you call `setUpControl()`, in there you create your `SmileyControls` and pass `smiley1` to it (which is `null` at that time).
After that you call `setUpSmiley()` which creates the instance of `Smiley`.

So you probably only have to call `setUpSmiley()` before you call `setUpControl()` and your problem should be solved.

Comment: That got rid of the NPE, thank you!!  But now my buttons won't repaint the eyes. I'm thinking its because I'm painting in a method that's not paintComponent?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order of these lines, as you use your `smiley1` variable before it gets its value:

```
    setUpControl(); // This uses smiley1
    setUpSmiley();  // This instantiates smiley1
```

### EDIT

You should move the drawing to the `paint*()` methods, or methods called directly from them.

That is, your `setEyeCondition()` method should set a property on the smiley, and the drawing should go into your `setEyes()`method.

Comment: That got rid of the NPE, thank you!!  But now my buttons won't repaint the eyes. I'm thinking its because I'm painting in a method that's not paintComponent?